# Sql Server TOP - used?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

Is there a keyword or metainformation in SQL Server that'll tell you if TOP took effect?

```
EX:
Select TOP 5 * From Stuff

RESULT: 5 rows
```

What is the best way to determine if there would have been 6 or more?

```
I could do:
SELECT TOP 6 count(*) FROM Stuff
```

But I am concerned about a separate call to retrieve the count because there actual query is much more complicated than this one and on a large table.

Thanks!

Comment: "Took effect" in what way?  Meaning that it actually limited your result set?  Just count what you got back.

Comment: @jonnyGold Counting what he got back wouldn't tell him if there were more rows available than he asked for.

Comment: @ean5533 Hence my asking for clarification about the meaning of "took effect"?

Comment: `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is pretty pointless - you'll get the `TOP` rows ordered by what?!?!

Comment: @jonnyGold I think it's clear what he's asking for. He's running a query that uses `TOP xxx` and he'd like to know if there's a way to tell if that `TOP` clause actually limited the result set or not. (i.e. if his query just happened to return 5 rows, or there were more rows but the `TOP` limited it)

Comment: @marc_s I don't think that's really the point of his question -- it's just a dummy query to illustrate his point. The presence of an `ORDER BY` wouldn't affect what he's asking.

Comment: My main concern is limiting the time a search may run.  If I give it a TOP 5000 even without an ORDER BY it will stop the query from running too long and still provide usable information to client.  I need to notify the client when that has occurred with a return code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could select the top N+1 (where N in your example is 5, so in your example select the top 6) and discard the last one in your client code, and use the presence of a sixth element to determine if TOP would have had an effect had you used N in the first place.  I am not sure there is much value of doing this, however.

Comment: wow.  It's been a long day.  Not sure how that didn't cross my mind.

Comment: Update/details: Because I want to configure the actual max result size on the server I'm returning @N as an output param to the client.  This allows the client to compare @N to the result count and display a message if need be.  This also allows patching to be much easier because of the distributed nature of the client.

Answer (score 12):

There is nothing automatic you can use. You could use something along these lines

```
DECLARE @N INT = 5;

WITH T
     AS (SELECT TOP (@N + 1) *
         FROM   master..spt_values
         ORDER  BY number)
SELECT TOP (@N) *,
             CASE
               WHEN Count(*) OVER () = (@N + 1) THEN 1
               ELSE 0
             END AS MoreRecords
FROM   T
ORDER  BY number
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand No, because his `WITH` only selected 6 rows.

Comment: @ean5533 Right, but the OP's `WITH` might not. I would probably demonstrate this using a variable.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - The OP's should have a `TOP 6` (or `TOP N+ 1`) so it can stop scanning after the 6th row.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Well that `TOP 6` is part of the logic Martin is suggesting. Martin, perhaps add a line to clarify that point?

Comment: Wouldn't the `CASE` clause be evaluated for every result record?

Comment: @jonnyGold - Yes but it only does the `COUNT` once

Comment: I see what you did here and maybe I should have been more clear with my example.  I'm thinking of capping at 5000 to prevent the query from running for hours.  Creating a temporary table does solve my first question and I like your solution but it may bring up a performance issue in itself.  I'll  most likely need to do some testing for that.

Comment: @LethalFlipper why do you think a temporary table won't introduce similar (or worse) performance issues?

Comment: @aaron.  I misspoke.  Temporary result set. Would that cause a performance hit?

Comment: @LethalFlipper - I would have thought Carl's answer will be more efficient TBH. It avoids the need for SQL Server to add a spool to the plan.

Answer (score 0):

You could append a boolean value into the query that returns true when COUNT(*) of a subquery with the same logic returns a value greater than 5 and false when it returns a value 5 or less.

This would add the information you need to the data being returned. If you are concerned about performance, and the query is extremely complicated, than this may not give a large improvement over separate queries, but should give at best a minor improvement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that without two queries or doing performance killing recacluations...

```
Select TOP 5 * From Stuff
```

and

```
Select Count(*) From Stuff
```

Comment: Not true, COUNT() OVER() can do this

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'd like to see the query plans to see which way is more effecient.

Comment: Feel free. Of all the solutions presented thus far, when I execute all together, Carl's and Martin's come out to 4% of the overall cost each. RedFilter's is 1% more at 5%, HLGEM's is 42%, and your suggestion combined for the other 44%. I did my tests against sys.all_columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 5 Field1, field2, recordcount 
FROM Stuff
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT  COUNT(*) as recordcount FROM Stuff) a
ORDER BY Field1
```

Comment: Note that I removed the SQL antipatterns of using SELECT  * and not using an ORDER BY when getting the TOP N records.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 5 *,
    case when count(*) OVER() <= 5 then 'yes' else 'no' end as AllRecordsReturned
from supportContacts
```